# Warning:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8

Tags: android, version, gradle-plugin

For this error i tried 2 ways:
1)Changed Settings > Builds,Execution,Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle >Gradle home path from gradle-2.8-all.zip to gradle-2.10-all.zip--- not worked

2)Edited Project\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties files field distributionUrl like this
from 
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
to 
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip--- no luck!

still getting above error. Any other ways???

P.S: each time i have done sync & then rebuild project but error occuring again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the latest gradle-2.10-all.zip from

http://gradle.org/gradle-download/

download from Complete Distribution link

open in android studio file ->settings ->gradle

open the path and paste the downloaded zip folder gradle-2.10 in that folder

change the gradle 2.8 to gradle 2.10 in file ->settings ->gradle

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gradle settings wrapper]

Go to your gradle settings and ensure that you're using the default gradle wrapper instead of a local one. If you are using the local one, you will need to drop in the 2.10 zip by hand.

Comment: Thanks Marx , i ended up doing the same.... i manually downloaded 2.10 gradle plugin ( from https://services.gradle.org/distributions/)  and pointed it in local location.Its working now! If pointed to default will it uses latest version always??